# Installing google appengine on Google Colab Notebook

Tags: google-app-engine, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import some files from my Google Cloud Storage bucket to a Google Colab Notebook. However, I face the following error using the snippet suggested by google.

Code:

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
# This only needs to be done once per notebook.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Download a file based on its file ID.
#
# A file ID looks like: laggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz
file_id = '1NKNtpuP95NKNMTVao6qt8G-OJs_xmbnC'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
print('Downloaded content "{}"'.format(downloaded.GetContentString()))
```

Error:

```
W0331 16:31:52.011976 139994604533632 __init__.py:44] file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect
    from google.appengine.api import memcache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 33, in <module>
    from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 37, in <module>
    from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 41, in autodetect
    from . import file_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 41, in <module>
    'file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0')
ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0

Downloaded content "{
  "attention_probs_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "hidden_size": 768,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 3072,
  "max_position_embeddings": 512,
  "num_attention_heads": 12,
  "num_hidden_layers": 12,
  "type_vocab_size": 2,
  "vocab_size": 28996
}
"
```

I understand that I have some modules missing and I need to install them. However, I tried

```
!export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"
!echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
!curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
!apt update && apt install google-cloud-sdk
```

And faced the following error:

```
deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt  main
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1326  100  1326    0     0  53040      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 53040
OK
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I am new to Google Colab Notebooks and while I understand that it's a simple interactive notebook I am not able to get the hang of this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in googleapiclient, the code bellow will sove it.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('googleapiclient.discovery_cache').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Ref : [Github Reference Error](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/299)

Comment: +1 for this answer. I've spent about 4 hours trying to hunt this problem out. The Google API was working fine, then broke when I made some changes. One of these changes, which went under the radar, was adding `import logging`. Out of the box, these two libraries don't appear to work correctly together - but this line resolved all of my problems.